# How to move marker from one position to another in WPF?

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

I am using GMap.net for Google Maps where i am able to place marker in the map.

I want to allow user to freely move marker to place it somewhere else on the map.

I have used this code in which i am using an image for marker and added event to move the image marker but whenever i try to move the image, the whole map start to move.
Please suggest me if any event available for marker move.

Note: This is for WPF

```
private void PlaceCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Double lat = Convert.ToDouble(this.Lattitude.Text);
  Double lng = Convert.ToDouble(this.Longitude.Text);
  marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(lat,lng));      

  Image newImage = new Image();
  Canvas.SetZIndex(newImage, 99);
  newImage.MouseLeftButtonDown += (ss, ee) =>
  {
    firstPoint = ee.GetPosition(this);
    newImage.CaptureMouse();
  };
  newImage.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
  {
    if (ee.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
      //-- Create temp point
      Point temp = ee.GetPosition(this);
      Point res = new Point(firstPoint.X - temp.X, firstPoint.Y - temp.Y);

      //-- Update image location
      Canvas.SetLeft(newImage, Canvas.GetLeft(newImage) - res.X);
      Canvas.SetTop(newImage, Canvas.GetTop(newImage) - res.Y);

      //-- Update first point
      firstPoint = temp;
    }
  };
  newImage.MouseUp += (ss, ee) => { newImage.ReleaseMouseCapture(); };

  BitmapImage testim = new BitmapImage();
  testim.BeginInit();
  testim.UriSource = new Uri("F:\\test.png");
  testim.EndInit();

  newImage.Source = testim;
  newImage.Height = 30;
  newImage.Width = 30;

  marker.Shape = newImage;
  MainMap.Markers.Add(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution from following link

Click [here] (https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps)

Watch for CustomMarkerDemo.xaml.cs and add this to your program. This custom marker has click event required by me!